# Conexão PHP com Dropbox em HTTP

Tags: php, https, dropbox

Acabei de fazer um teste para implementar em um aplicativo web a conexão com o Dropbox, funcionou aparentemente tudo bem exceto por só funcionar em localhost, o que faz com que ele até pegue a permissão do dropbox mas não traz de volta para o app. Dentro do dropbox não consigo adicionar o link de redirecionamento por ser HTTP, informa que só funciona com HTTPS ou localhost. Tentei até usar alguns programas como Wampserver para testar mas este por exemplo não funciona por usar o PHP 32bits, outros nem consegui instalar. Alguém tem alguma dica pra mim, preciso colocar o app para funcionar e apresentar ao cliente, caso ele aprove colocarei no site dele e vou exigir a conexão HTTPS se isto se mostrar necessário, mas por enquanto quero apenas que funcione para testar e terminar o desenvolvimento.

Grato desde já

Comment: Faz um site no https://sites.google.com
Ele trabalhar com https e é free

Comment: Depois que me liguei no que tu realmente precisava implementar.
A resposta realmente não serviria.
Mas dá olhada nisso aqui: http://www.comodobr.com/instantssl/certificado_ssl_livre.php

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/62792)

Comment: Ok Diego, mas eu não tenho acesso aos códigos do White Dark.
E a dúvida dele, pelo que entendi, se deu no sentido de como usar https para testar. 
O link indica um certificado SSL grátis por 30 dias, para que el possa testar a aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado Vitor, vou verificar o link.

Comment: Gostei muito do serviço, aparentemente fica até mais simples de fazer do que como eu teria normalmente pois tenho uma revenda usando WHM. Aparentemente com este serviço não vou precisar contratar um IP fixo para cada cliente caso queira usar SSL em vários, pois na revenda o IP é um só.

Comment: Funcionou aqui!!! Agradeço demais Vítor!!! Além de resolver meu problema vc ainda conseguiu me ajudar de tabela a aprender perfeitamente como instalar um certificado SSL aqui que meu outro cliente só entra no site dele usando https, pq não sei, e fica pedindo pra que isso pare de dar erro, enfim, muito obrigado.